# how to read speaker notes from google slides using flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-docs-api

There is a similar question at:

[Can I get speaker notes from Google Slides by API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40713058/can-i-get-speaker-notes-from-google-slides-by-api)

and documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/notes

But I can't get it working in flutter.

```
var ssMap = pp.slides.asMap();
ssMap.forEach((key, slide) {
    print('Slide: ${key} : ${slide}  ');
    var notesId = slide.slideProperties.notesPage.notesProperties.speakerNotesObjectId;
    print("NOTE: " + notesId.toString());
```

How do I read speaker's notes?

Comment: About which problem did you encounter while implementing? Your code snippet is pretty short. Can you expand it?

Comment: The Documentation says:

_To find a slide's speaker note shape, find the slide's notes Page in its SlideProperties message. The shape containing the speaker notes text is identified by the speakerNotesObjectId field in the notes page's NotesProperties message._

I got this with 
'''
var notesId = slide.slideProperties.notesPage.notesProperties.speakerNotesObjectId;
'''

_To read a slide's speaker notes, find an object with this ID on the notes page and read its text._

How do I find an object by ID and read its text?